# how to create .doc or word file in iphone by code

Tags: iphone, ios, ms-word, .doc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a word file programmatically from collected data in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409859/how-to-generate-a-word-file-programmatically-from-collected-data-in-iphone-sdk)

My requirement is to generate a report in a Word file in my iOS app.

I searched it but did not find any appropriate way to do that. I've found `libopc` which is not very helpful.

Does anyone have any proper way or any sdk which can create *.doc* file from give set of data to do it?

Comment: i think this will help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255529/how-to-write-a-msword-doc-file-in-objective-c